# How to hatch eggs and walk your buddy pokemon while staying at home?

Tags: pokemon-go

I would like to know if there are any ways to hatch eggs and gain kilometers for my buddy pokemon while still staying indoors.

I would really like to profit from the fact that now eggs hatch twice as fast but I cannot really leave my home because of corona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know how you feel and I have been looking for different ways to benefit from the current offers. I found a little trick which made my player walk around while being indoors.

The trick will make your buddy Pokemon find candies and your eggs hatch fast. It even makes my guy player reach a nearby gym and a couple of pokestops. The trick is to toggle your WiFi every X minutes. This means, that every 15 minutes, your guy will walk as WiFi affects the GPS accuracy. I have automated this process by using IFTTT app. As you aren't really spoofing your location, this won't be considered as cheating. I have written a blog post with detailed instructions: https://www.khalidalnajjar.com/how-to-walk-more-than-70-km-a-week-in-pokemon-go-without-walking/

As a side note, having adventure sync enabled and a Pokemon go plus device connected at all times helps in hatching eggs and catching Pokemon.

Answer (score 1):

The only legitimate answer to me is Adventure Sync. Get some $15 fitness band and link it to PoGo. Other ways are just exploiting or spoofing - especially if you use 3rd party to increase your distance walked.

Answer (score 1):

No need for any wifi trick, GPS drifting, or any other 3rd party device. Just walk around in house with your phone in your pocket.

Adventure Sync when paired with Google Fit will track the number of steps you take, that means even walking around the house, you will be able to get a surprising amount of steps and distance. This is not only legitimate but rewarding especially if you stuff in the house like vacuuming or gardening or whatever.

Another option on top of this, if you really don't want to walk at all is to rock your phone (shake your phone around an approximate walking pace). This is similar to if you were just on a treadmill in the house so it is still technically legit steps.